# Call metapost with command line arguments through shell-escape; then include the resulting graphics

Tags: metapost, shell-escape

I would like to use metapost to draw long curved lines and overset the resulting images over long subformulas instead of relatively short widetilde.
Would be great if I can choose not from the set of pregenerated variants, but rather generate on the fly, passing the length of the subformula as the command line argument.

What can the \write18 command look like for such case?

The metapost code for drawing the line:

```
beginfig(1)
  picture tmp; tmp := btex $x_s + u_s t$ etex;
  w := xpart(urcorner tmp - llcorner tmp);  h := 1.5;
  pickup pencircle scaled .3; linecap := butt;
  draw (0,0)..{right}(w/4+w/16,h)..(w/2,h/2)..{right}(3w/4-w/16,0)..(w,h);
endfig;
end
```

The problem is partially solved with gmp package, kudos to Thurston.

Comment: You can use the [`gmp` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/gmp) or switch to `lualatex` and use [`luamplib`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luamplib) to do this.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the gmp package, I'll definitely try it.

Comment: gmp does its job, but interferes with labels in amsmath environments

Comment: My recommendation is that you move to `lualatex` and use the built-in Metapost support via `luamplib`

Comment: I needed this for just one article of many in my journal, so not to break the workflow I  made a local copy of gmp instead and commented the labels in it.